# Random freezing / hanging in Python ZeroMQ

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am writing a broker-less, balanced, client-worker service written in python with **`ZeroMQ`**.

The clients acquire a worker's address, establish a connection ( `zmq.REQ / zmq.REP` ), send single request, receive a single response and then disconnect.

I have chosen a broker-less architecture because the amount of a data that needs to get transferred between the clients and workers is relatively large, despite there only being a single `REQ/REP` pair per connection, and using a broker as a 'middle man' would create a bottleneck.

While testing the system, I noticed that the communication between the clients and workers was halting randomly, only sometimes resuming after a couple of seconds (**often several minutes**).

I narrowed down the issue to the `.connect()` / `.disconnect()` of clients to workers.

I have written two small python scripts that reproduce the bug.

```
import zmq

class Site:

      def __init__(self):
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.pair_socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)
        self.num = 0


      def __del__(self):
        print "closed"


      def run_site(self):
        print "running..."
        while True:
            self.pair_socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
            print 'connected'
            self.pair_socket.send_pyobj(self.num)
            print 'sent', self.num
            print self.pair_socket.recv_pyobj()
            self.pair_socket.disconnect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
            print 'disconnected'
            self.num += 1

s = Site()
s.run_site()
```

and

```
import zmq

class Server:

      def __init__(self):
          ctx = zmq.Context()
          self.pair_socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
          self.pair_socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')


      def __del__(self):
          print " closed"


      def run_server(self):
          print "running..."
          while True:
              x =  self.pair_socket.recv_pyobj()
              print x
              self.pair_socket.send_pyobj(x)


s = Server()  
s.run_server()
```

I don't think the issue is related to memory or **`gc`** as I have tried disabling `gc` - without much affect.

I have tried using **`zmq.LINGER`** as described here: [Zeromq with python hangs if connecting to invalid socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939977/zeromq-with-python-hangs-if-connecting-to-invalid-socket)

**What could cause these randoms freezes?**

Comment: Use a packet sniffer to see which side of the pair is hanging... does the message hang on the client before it sends out, or does it hang on the server after it receives it.  How do you determine a freeze, i.e. what is the last message you see before a freeze starts?

Comment: With all due respect, designing a **`while True: .connect(); ... ; .disconnect()`** is rather a **brutal** way, with respect to underlying resources and associated system overheads. There are sure much better and "more ecological" / "Greener" ways to express your design intentions in code, that would not waste CPU / resources allocations

Answer (score 0):

The `REP` socket is synchronous by definition. So your server can only serve one request at a time, rest of them will just fill up the buffer and get lost at some point.

To fix the root cause, you need to use the `ROUTER` socket instead.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.pair_socket = ctx.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
        self.pair_socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
        self.poller = zmq.Poller()
        self.poller.register(self.pair_socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    def __del__(self):
        print " closed"

    def run_server(self):
        print "running..."
        while True:
            try:
                items = dict(self.poller.poll())
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
            if self.pair_socket in items:
                x = self.pair_socket.recv_multipart()
                print x
                self.pair_socket.send_multipart(x)
```